# Exported feature with roles not imported when loading module

Tags: 8, features

**TLDR;** I'd like to export the permissions I've added to the `authenticated` role, and have them appear on a different server when installing the custom module. However, when I install the module on a fresh server, the permissions for the `authenticated` user remain as default, but I can see in `admin/config/development/features` that there are pending changes, and once I import them the settings are correctly applied. Why aren't they applied on loading the module?

## Steps to reproduce

First I log into a blank dev site, navigate to `admin/people/permissions` and add the *Article: Create new content* permission for the `authenticated` user (which I know is `create article content` from looking at the page source in my browser).

I now navigate to `admin/config/development/features/edit` and select *Roles->Authenticate user (authenticated)*, pick a module name, enable *Mark all config as required* and click *Download Archive*.

The result is a module that contains 3 files:

#### my_module.features.yml

```
required: true
```

#### my_module.info.yml

```
name: 'my module'
type: module
core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - user
```

Since I'm using `9.0.7` I changed this to;

```
name: 'my module'
type: module
core_version_requirement: '^8 || ^9'
dependencies:
  - user
```

#### config/install/user.role.authenticated.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: authenticated
label: 'Authenticated user'
weight: 1
is_admin: false
```

For some reason `Features` didn't pick up my permission changes, so I changed this manually to;

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: authenticated
label: 'Authenticated user'
weight: 1
is_admin: false
permissions:
  - 'create article content'
```

Now I tried to install the module by copying it to `/modules/custom/my_module` and running `drush en my_module` on a completely clean site. However, when I navigate to `admin/people/permissions` I see this:

[image]

When I go to `admin/config/development/features/diff/my_module` I can see that my features were correctly interpreted, just not applied:

[image]

If I now select *Import Changes* the permissions apply correctly. But why aren't they already applied, when the `my_module` module is clearly enabled?

I tried playing around with the `weight` value in `user.role.authenticated.yml` to no avail (I changed it to 9999 and -9999 but it didn't seem to have any impact).

The fact that I had to modify my `user.role.authenticated.yml` indicates that something has perhaps gone wrong at the export step, but I don't know enough about the features module to know if these events are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a workaround. If leymannx or someone else come up with a better solution I'll mark it as the answer, but in the meantime I thought I'd provide my hack-around to get this working:

#### my_module.install

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 *
 * Install functions for my_module
 */

use Drupal\user\Entity\Role;

/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 *
 * Perform actions to set up the site for this profile.
 *
 * @see system_install()
 */
function my_module_install() {
  $role_object = Role::load('authenticated');
  $role_object->grantPermission('create article content');
  $role_object->save();
}
```

This causes the permission to be correctly applied.

Answer (score 2):

You need to un-exclude user permissions first.

Go to /admin/config/development/features > Select your bundle > (Tab) Configure Bundles > Alter (Configure) > Uncheck "Strip out user permissions."

Then recreate the feature.

---

I've also already been [there](https://www.drupal.org/project/features/issues/2383439#comment-12584035).

Comment: This causes the permissions to be exported. It's helpful to know because it means I don't have to manually add the permissions to my `user.role.authenticated.yml` file anymore, but doesn't change the undesirable behaviour that enabling the module doesn't import the permissions. Note that I still have to manually add the `core_version_requirement: '^8 || ^9'` line as well so I'm wondering if this is a drupal 9.x issue. I noticed that  you removed the `9` tag from the post. Do you mind if I revert it?

Comment: @quant – No problem, it's just you need to choose only one. Seems `9` is a better fit. And it also seems more of a bug. Though I'm not sure if it's Features or core. What happens when before you enable the Feature on the other site you remove the authenticated user role from this site? Does the role get recreated AND the permissions get set then?

Comment: I tried changing my drupal version to `8.9.7` and had the same problem, so it's not a version 9 issue after all. I don't know how to delete the `authenticated` role but when I created a `test` role and applied the same module (with `authenticated` replaced with `test`) the permissions import correctly. So now we've narrowed this down to being an issue to do with the `authenticated` user somehow..

Comment: Well, I've got a workaround, but I'm not proud of it: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297557/59466

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you to stop using features and use [drush](https://www.drush.org/) instead
You can easily export your config using `drush cex -y` (cex = config export) and import it using `drush cim -y` (cim = config import).

Comment: When syncing config from one multi-site instance to another, that simple Drush config routine you described isn't much of a help. It's also not what OP was asking for.

Comment: Syncing from one multi-site instance to another one is pretty simple since you just need to erase the old yml files, put the new files in the same directory and run the command. And as I already met problems like he described with `features` but never with `drush` the suggestion still makes sense ;)

Comment: This is good to know, but I don't think it helps with my issue.

Comment: If you choose not to use drush and keep using features, you're right it won't help you. But if you choose starting using drush it will help you as you won't have your issue anymore.

Comment: 100 multi-site instances and manually copying 100 of config around. No way.

Comment: I don't copy them manually, they are commited with git

Comment: OP is talking about syncing one or more isolated features like a paragraph type with all its fields and settings, or a content type with all its fields and settings, or here a user role to one or potentially many more **completely different sites or multi-site instances**. That's what Features is for. After it gets enabled or imported on the other site(s) or instance(s) **config is managed and exported for deployment as usual**. Features is used for diffing and syncing isolated features during development across multiple different or unrelated site(s) or instance(s). Your answer is of no help.

Comment: I tried using `drush cim --partial /path/to/yml` and it just says `[notice] There are no changes to import` so I don't think the behaviour is different to using features. I agree with @leymannx in that using drush doesn't really seem like a practical solution, even if it did work.